# Is there a way to create sqlite3 db file automatically

Tags: sqlite

**I have a script as belows:**

CREATE TABLE myTestTable1();

INSERT INTO myTestTable1 VALUES();

......

CREATE TABLE myTestTable2();

INSERT INTO myTestTable2 VALUES();

......

**any guys knows how to create a db file from the script?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import .sql file to SQLite by using this http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

Comment: Thanks. But the SQlite Browser will force close when I attempt to import the sql file. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I did not tested it, I posted because there i saw an option to import sql. Anyways, I am also working on a similar project. I have converted mysql to sqlite by fetching the results from a server as xml, parsed and then storing it in a sqlite database. You can pull it from File Explorer :)